# What's the deal with the "blatantly off-topic" close flag?

Tags: support, flagging

I don't remember there being a flag like this for some time (but then again, I haven't flagged a question as being off-topic for some time also). Searching MSE, MSO and here didn't turn up any meaningful results. The help page is vague in this aspect. I then ask:

- What is the "blatantly off-topic" flag? What is is worth for?
- How is it handled differently than the other flags?

Comment: Where did you see it?

Comment: Here, at SuperUser. Flag a question, close for other reasons, off-topic, then blatantly off-topic appears as the second last item.

Comment: Which question did you see it on? It is possible that a user put in a custom reason for it being closed and it is being carried forward on that question.  I do not see the flag you mention on a random question I picked.

Comment: Got a question link on that?

Comment: I was actually on the review queue. The link is this: http://superuser.com/review/first-posts/242672 . I should add that this close reason also exists on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I guess this is related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257883/why-do-we-not-have-an-off-topic-flag-for-closing-as-off-topic

Comment: @OliverSalzburg thanks. I don't know how I missed that answer, but it does explain the close flag.

Comment: that flag reason is new, there's no need to delete the question